# Power BI Desktop: Refresh data error 'Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported

Tags: mysql, powerbi

When I try refreshing dataset I get error:

```
An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework.'
```

Used to work fine before, I get data from a remote MySQL database on AWS server
Checked collation of columns is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

- .Net framework version: `4.8`
- MySQL connector version: `8.0.16` Also tried on latest version
- Power BI Desktop version: `2.100.1182.0`    64-bit (December 2021)

Any idea?

Comment: Well, somewhere there must be a reference to utf8mb3. It may be in a connection string, config file - you need to find it and change it. Btw, character set and collation are two related, yet different things.

Comment: Checked all tables columns one by one in MySQL Workbench
Character Set and Collation are both set to utf8mb4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

The report was built based on MySQL database
However, MySQL database has been converted to MariaDB which caused utf8mb3 errors when establishing connection.
The new connection was established using connector-odbc-3.1.4 available on https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.1.4/
And data source settings were changed from MySQL Database to MariaDB, which resulted in datasets being treated as a completely new source.

Comment: That's not really clear - why is the solution for a MYSQL related issue to use a MariaDB connector, and how do you even do that?  

The other solution in this post, downgrading to 8.0.28 resolved this issue for me: but that's not really a 'solution', it's a workaround until the latest connector is actually fixed.

Comment: Well, as mentioned in the answer, "MySQL database has been converted to MariaDB" on server, that's why in my case MariaDB connector worked.

Answer (score 6):

As of 24th May 2022,
Mysql/NET connector **version 8.0.28** should be the one in use on your PowerBI Desktop and On-premise gateway

Source of solution : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/unable-to-connect-to-mysql/td-p/2493084